# What is the context variable for detailview class in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-class-based-views

Django's generic view class ListView has object_list as context variable, what is the context variable for the DetailView?

My view is,

```
class MyDetail(DetailView):
   model = Mymodel
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context data for a [`DetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) class contains the `"object"` key, which points to the object that the view is operating on.

You can use a different key if you override the `get_context_data()` method of the view, e.g.:

```
 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
     context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
     context["my_object"] = self.object
     return context
```

Comment: I tried the default 'object' like {{object.myfield}} but it displays blank?

Comment: Can `myfield` be blank? Try `{{ object.id }}` instead.

Comment: {{ object.id }} is blank as well.

Comment: Try setting `template_name = "<your-template-name>"` under `model` and see if it helps.

Comment: setting template_name  did not help.

Comment: Also make sure the template is not set in your `urls.py`, as an argument to `.as_view()` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the context object name by using :

```
context_object_name = 'your_object_name'
```

Include this in the class in your View. By default, the object name is 'object' , but it is always good to use an object name of your choice. It makes it more intuitive!